# how I can create multiple comparators in a single object

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a object Contact

```
public class Contact(){
   private Integer idContact
   private Date dateDebut;
    private Date dateFin;
    ...............
   public Contact(){}
  // getters and setters
}
```

and `List<Contact>` contacts
I want to find the Object having the minimum of dateDebut and the Object having maximum of dateFin using `Collections.sort(contacts)` or other method.

Comment: Create new `Comparator` class. It has little to do with the `Contact` class anyway.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an inline anonymous `Comparator` class and assign it to a constant:

```
public static final Comparator<Contact> DATE_DEBUT_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Contact>() {
    public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {
        return c1.dateDebut.compareTo(c2.dateDebut);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)`

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
static Comparator<Contact> DATEDEBUT_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Contact first, Contact second) {
       assert(first != null);
       assert(second != null);
       return first.getDateDebut().compareTo(second.getDateDebut());
    }   
}

static Comparator<Contact> DATEFIN_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Contact first, Contact second) {
       assert(first != null);
       assert(second != null);
       return first.getDateFin().compareTo(second.getDateFin());
    }   
}
```

Comment: @CHHIBI AMOR both objects have to be `not null` cause if they are you may encounter a `NullPointerException` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
static Comparator<Contact> DATE_DEBUT_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Contact first, Contact second) {
           return first.getDateDebut().compareTo(second.getDateDebut());
        }  
        // Ascending order of debut date
    };


static Comparator<Contact> DATEFIN_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Contact first, Contact second) {
      return second.getDateFin().compareTo(first.getDateFin());
    }   
    // Descending order of fin date
};
```

Passing comprator to Collections Util, can find object with min debut date at first location of Arraylist

```
Collections.sort(contactList, DATE_DEBUT_COMPARATOR);
```

Similarly passing comprator to Collections Util, can find object with max fin date at first location of Arraylist

```
Collections.sort(contactList, DATE_FIN_COMPARATOR);
```